# Terraform Apply Failed - InvalidUserData.Malformed: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-cdk

Question:
How do you use base64encode Terraform Function in [cdktf](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk)?

From what I could find, these [Terraform Function](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/leveraging-built-in-terraform-functions-in-cdktf/17118)  are not supported yet.
Or are they now?

My usecase is to "load BASE64 encoded [userData for an ec2 launchTemplate](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#user_data)"

When I try using a [nodejs method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to do the same:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';`
.
.
const userTemplate = readFileSync('./user_template.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'});
.
.
const launchTemplate = new LaunchTemplate(this, "launchTemplate", {
.
.
userData: userTemplate,
.
```

It fails with this error:

> **Error: InvalidUserData.Malformed: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data.**

Any suggestions how I could pass userData to  LaunchTemplate using cdktf?

Comment: Have you tried base64 encoding it with nodejs instead and then passing that base64 string as the parameter?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. 
In the above example, I have tried using readFileSync nodejs method.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue.
It seems object created by [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) returns buffer or String based on what you pass.
When I pass it like this

```
const userTemplate = readFileSync('./user_template.txt', 'base64');
```

It returns string encoded in base64.
That is exactly what I was after.